# Apply title case ("proper case") to an entire spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The [PROPER function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/proper-function-52a5a283-e8b2-49be-8506-b2887b889f94?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) in Microsoft Excel:

> Capitalizes the first letter in a text string and any other letters in text that follow any character other than a letter. Converts all other letters to lowercase letters.

I have a spreadsheet that has hundreds of rows, each row with dozens of columns, and I want to apply the PROPER function (or a similar "capitalize the first letter of each word, lowercase the rest" transformation) to every cell, in-place. When I'm done, the old (all uppercase) values are no longer needed--I only need the transformed versions.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: not really an excel solution, but fast. [ Select All , copy > paste in Notepad++ | Select all > Edit >Convert Case to > Proper Case | Select All , copy > paste in excel ]

Comment: another quick and dirty way: Suppose you have data in `A1:FZ999`. 1. In `GA1` write `=PROPER(A1)`; 2. copy/drag down and to the right until all your data is represented; 3. for the new range copy then paste values; 4. Delete original columns `A:FZ`

Comment: Thanks @AlexM, that works, although it's not in in-place solution, and is a little cumbersome when dealing with very large CSVs. I decided to go with a Notepad++ pre-processing solution (open the CSV in Notepad++, CTRL-A, ALT-U, CTRL-S). Pretty straightforward, was just wondering if there was a way to do this entirely in Excel.

I use Notepad++ quite a lot, though, so this will work for me.

Comment: That makes sense - not sure if Notepad++ was part of a good answer for you. I think you should write yours up as an answer and select it as the chosen answer, since it worked for you. Opening the CSV IN Notepad++ is a key element to a good solution here

Answer (score 1):

Not really an excel solution, but fast.

[ Select All(in excel) , copy > paste in Notepad++

| Select all(in notepad++) > Edit >Convert Case to > Proper Case

| Select All(in notepad++) , copy > paste in excel ]

Comment: So this was something I experimented with, but I was concerned that in some cases the cell location would be lost, e.g., if cells contained tabs or other special characters.

I wound up adopting a similar strategy with Notepad++, however: 1) Open CSV in Notepad++, CTRL-A, ALT-U (converts to "proper" case), CTRL-S. After that I can open the CSV in Excel and the case is as desired.

Comment: Congratulations, glad it solves.. ( :

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=UPPER(LEFT(A1,1))&LOWER(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this isn't an in-place transformation, it gives me the new text in different cells.

Comment: Try to provide the sample and modify your question.